# Swing runnable jar using bootstrap

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, swing

I have a Java Swing application but I want to improve the user interface screen. Can I use bootstrap framework in my Swing application?

Comment: check this https://dzone.com/articles/htmlcssjavascript-gui-java-0

Comment: I don't understand your premise that shoving HTML components into a desktop application will *"improve the user interface screen"*. As an aside, the 'look and feel' of a Swing application is controlled by the pluggable look and feel - so perhaps use a different one, or design your own custom PLAF. But if you really think you can get a better look using HTML / CSS, use Java-FX - which is much more designed along those lines.

Comment: No you can't. The only one way to improve Swing look is to [change the used Look-and-Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html). And [here](https://www.jwrapper.com/blog/6-great-look-and-feels-to-make-your-java-app-pretty) is the list of Look-and-Feels you may use for your application.

Comment: Why not just write a Web App?

Comment: I want my application to be lightweight. I will try Java-FX

Comment: *"I want my application to be lightweight."* You perception is **still** skewed. A 'light weight' GUI in the traditional sense might be an HTML interface with simple controls that leaves the rendering of those controls to a browser. But the other end of the equation is a 'rich client' GUI as might be found in either Swing **or** Java-FX. Just because the latter can render a lightweight GUI does not make the entire app. lightweight! In fact, I regard it as 'the worst of all worlds'. And a tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: I bet an equivalent Swing app would be close to the same byte size as a JavaFX app and have a similar level of complexity - choose the platform which performs the functionality you need - not what it looks like - I’ll take functionality over form any day (although I love a sexy UI to, but if I can’t use it - it’s a waste of pixels)

Answer (score 0):

Refer below the 
1)Use eclipse(eclipse-SDK-3.8.2-win32.zip) in rendering HTML with java swing. see this link for eclipse files http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/
2)Use SWT binaries, download link http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/download.php?dropFile=swt-3.8.2-win32-win32-x86.zip
3)From the downloaded swt binaries, copy swt.jar from your project
4)For the code in rendering HTML see this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwklrRefSa4

Note the version of eclipse and SWT must have the same version.